# Executing command remotely on another linux server from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, server

I have a shell-script which extract details from a log file between two dates and executes a command on the output to generate some report. The log files are on different server and scripts are executed on different server. the Script looks like :

```
#!/bin/sh
time1=$1
time2=$2
echo `ssh -i key  user@ip -yes cat file | awk '{if(substr($4,2)>="'$time1'" && substr($4,2)<="'$time2'") print $0;}'` > tmp.log

`cat tmp.log | some operation to get detail`
```

The output expected to be in multiple lines like :

```
ip1 date1 - - request1 file1 method1 status1 
ip2 date2 - - request2 file2 method2 status2
```

But the output generated (by my command) is getting concatenated into a single line, containing all the details, like:

```
 ip1 date1 - - request1 file1 method1 status1 ip2 date2 - - request2 file2 method2 status2
```

When the command is executed directly on the server it generates desired output but not when executed remotely.
So my question is how would I get the correct output and is this a good way to do it ?

Comment: The `echo` in backticks is not only silly, but wrong.  Simply replace `echo \`whatever\`` with `whatever`.  See also http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo

Comment: Removing backticks is not producing any output.

Comment: Thank you I got it backticks neglects **\n**. so what I did is added the command inside **" "**.Like this : `echo "\`command\`"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments above you are still using "echo". @tripleee is correct. Don't. Also don't use the pointless cat at the start - simply redirect std in to your next command.

```
#!/bin/sh
time1=$1
time2=$2
ssh -i key  user@ip -yes cat file | awk '{if(substr($4,2)>="'$time1'" && substr($4,2)<="'$time2'") print $0;}' > tmp.log

some operation to get detail <tmp.log
```